# Connecting to MS Access 2010 using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

How to connect to MS Access 2010 which is in .accdb format using C#. Apparently the OleDbConnection throws an exception of 'Unrecognized database format'.

Comment: connectionstrions.com is your friend http://connectionstrings.com/access#p20

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your connection string should be of the format:

`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccess2007file.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;`

See [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007#p20)

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing you are still using Jet engine 4

try this connection string

`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccess2007file.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;`

Comment: To state an obvious fact, this will work only on copies of Windows where either Access is installed, or the ACE has been separately installed. Jet 4, on the other hand, is installed on all copies of Windows starting with Win2000.

Comment: I use the Data Sources wizard to generate the connection string for me.  You can find this in the settings.settings file.

Answer (score -1):

IF you password For ACESSS DataBase

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb;
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyDbPassword;